# Operating with the Weyl transform on a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space, deformation-quantization

I'm very new to studying quantum mechanics in phase space, so I'm trying to demonstrate some results that I see in books to get used to the formalism. I recently got stuck when i applied the Weyl map $Q[a]$ to a wave function $\psi(z)$. In other words, I'm trying to demonstrate the following result:

$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}[a][\psi(z)] = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)}\int dp \int dy a\Big(\frac{x+y}{2},p\Big)e^{\frac{i(x-y)}{\hslash}}\psi(y)   \
\end{equation}$$

To demonstrate this result, I started from here:
$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x,p)e^{\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}(x-\hat{x})+\frac{iy}{\hslash}(p-\hat{p})}\psi(z)\,dy\,d\sigma\,dx\,dp
\end{equation}$$

First, I rewrote the above equation, regrouping the exponential as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
    \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)]= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x,p)e^{{\frac{i}{\hslash}(x\sigma+\tau p})}e^{\frac{-i}{\hslash}(\sigma\hat{x}+\tau \hat{p})}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx\,dp 
\end{eqnarray}

Second, in the last exponential that appears above, I used Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff identity, like this:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq: bch}
    e^{A+B} = e^{A}e^{B}e^{-\frac{[A,B]}{2}}.
\end{equation}
Where a i took:
\begin{align*}
    A = -\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}\hat{x}\\
    B = -\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}\hat{p}.
\end{align*}
So:
\begin{eqnarray*}
    e^{-\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}\hat{x}-\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}\hat{p}} = e^{-\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}\hat{x}}e^{-\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}\hat{p}}e^{\frac{i\tau\sigma}{2\hslash}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I then substitute these results into the third integral:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=&  \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x,p)e^{{\frac{i}{\hslash}(x\sigma+\tau p})}e^{-\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}\hat{x}}e^{-\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}\hat{p}}e^{\frac{i\tau\sigma}{2\hslash}}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx\,dp
\end{eqnarray*}

Third, I then did the math on this last integral above as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=&  \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x,p)e^{{\frac{i}{\hslash}(x\sigma+\tau p})}e^{-\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}\hat{x}}e^{-\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}\hat{p}}e^{\frac{i\tau\sigma}{2\hslash}}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx\,dp \\ &=&
    \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x,p)e^{\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}(x+\frac{\tau}{2}-\hat{x})}e^{\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}(p-\hat{p})}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx\,dp
    \end{eqnarray*}

Taking:
\begin{align*}
    x'= x+\frac{\tau}{2} \rightarrow x = x' - \frac{\tau}{2}\\
\end{align*}

Then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
     \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=& \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}(x'-\hat{x})}e^{\frac{i\tau}{\hslash}(p-\hat{p})}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx'\,dp \\ &=&\frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma x'}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{-i\sigma \hat{x}}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{-i\tau \hat{p}}{\hslash}}\psi(z)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx'\,dp \\&=& \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma x'}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{-i\sigma \hat{x}}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx'\,dp \\&=& \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma x'}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{-i\sigma(z-\tau)}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx'\,dp 
     \\&=& \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^{2}}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma x'}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{-i\sigma z}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{i\sigma \tau}{\hslash}}e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau\,d\sigma\,dx'\,dp
    \end{eqnarray*}

Fourth, I then realized that by putting the factor $\frac{\sigma i}{\hslash}$ in evidence, in the last equation above, it is possible to regroup the terms of the exponents and write:

\begin{eqnarray*}
        \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=& \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)^2}\iiiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)e^{\frac{i\sigma}{\hslash}(x'-z+\tau)}\,d\sigma\,dx'e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau \,dp
    \end{eqnarray*}

Fifth, I performed integration in $\sigma$ along with a factor $\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}$, to make the dirac delta function appear, so:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] = \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\iiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)\delta(x'-z+\tau)\,dx'e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau \,dp
\end{eqnarray}$$

Using the delta definition, I arrive at:

\begin{eqnarray*}
        \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=& \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\iiint a(x' - \frac{\tau}{2},p)\delta(x'-z+\tau)\,dx'e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau \,dp\\ &=&
\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\iint a(-z+\tau - \frac{\tau}{2},p)\,dx'e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau \,dp \\ &=&
\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\iint a(\frac{\tau}{2}-z,p)\,dx'e^{\frac{i\tau p}{\hslash}}\psi(z-\tau)\,d\tau \,dp
\end{eqnarray*}

I realized that this last equation is almost the result I want to demonstrate. Some references I've seen when reaching this point use a variable change that provides the final expression. I have tried several substitutions like

$$\begin{equation}
y= z - \tau
\end{equation}$$

But with this substitution I get the following weird result:
\begin{eqnarray*}
        \mathbf{Q}(a)[\psi(z)] &=&
-\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\iint a(\frac{-\tau-z}{2},p)\,dx'e^{\frac{i(z-y)p}{\hslash}}\psi(y)\,dy \,dp
\end{eqnarray*}

I've done it and redid it in as many different ways as possible. What am I missing? Or what am I wrong?

In advance, I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misbegotten Weyl relation you are trying to prove is meaningless. The correct, meaningful, relation you should be considering, instead, is the coordinate representation one,
$$\begin{equation}
[\mathbf{Q}[a] ~\psi](x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hslash)}\!\int\!\! dp dy ~~a\Big(\frac{x+y}{2},p\Big)e^{\frac{i(x-y)}{\hslash}}\psi(y)   \
\end{equation}.$$

The left hand side you need to process is ***defined*** as
$$
{\large \langle x|} \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}\!\int\!\! d\tau d\sigma dx' dp ~~a(x',p) ~e^{i\tau(\hat p -p)/\hbar+i\sigma (\hat x -x')/\hbar} {\large |\psi\rangle }\\
= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}\!\int\!\! d\tau d\sigma dx' dp ~~a(x',p) ~e^{i  (p\tau+\sigma\tau /2+(x'-x)\sigma)/\hbar }\psi (x\!-\!\tau) \\ 
= \frac{2}{2\pi\hbar}\!\int\!\! d\tau   dx' dp ~~a(x',p)~\delta\left (\tau+2(x'-x)\right ) ~e^{i  p\tau  /\hbar  }  \psi (x\!-\!\tau),
$$
which is your target expression after a change of variables, $y=2x'-x$.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the difference? For me, this expression that you wrote is the same as the expression that I want to prove that I wrote in my first equation in the question.

Comment: There is no *z* in all this. You can't have a l.h.s. with a variable not present on the r.h.s. ... It should then be all straightforward, from there on...  Again, make sure the free and dummy integration variables on all subsequent expressions are properly balanced, demarcated, and contrasted...

Comment: Thank you, I will check your observations.